# Malware getting added to cart page magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, malware

I have a website hosted in magento 1.9 and it has been affected by a malware code on cart page.
I know magento 1.9 is old and should move my website to magento 2, and of course we are doing it but right now I need to remove that malware from my website.
Details:
This is the website url - https://www.great-save.com/
Malware is a js code and I can see it on cart pages at the end but only in mozilla browser and not in google chrome. Malware in mozilla browser.

[image]

There is no malware in google chrome

[image]

When I open this link then I can see a code like this.
[image]

I tried looking for this script using grep through all the files and also tried to search it using file name, but did not find anything. I looked in the Miscellaneous HTMl section in admin panel and there is no such script added.
[image]

I have also searched the database trying to find the word, in the url if it was added there but did not find anything.
[image]

My question is How I can go on debugging this issue to locate the files from where it is loaded.
In the network tab I see the file getting loaded while inspecting.
[image]

**Update:** I tried using grep to locate the malware inside my public_html directory but did not get anything.

[image]

Comment: With grep command find that  and also inform https://aathitiyapravash.in/ to remove malware file.
Sorry if you think not technical .

Comment: grep did not give any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a tool eComscan to scan my website for malware. It listed out the malware.
https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner

Answer (score 0):

Run below command in ssh to findout js add from which file

```
grep -r 'jQuery_v176.js' app/
```

Comment: I have updated my question according to your suggestion, plz have a look

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same malware injection. I used the following command to find the injection: grep -r ‘base64’ app/

It showed a list of all the files using base64 and the malware was injected in file: /app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php line 164.

Please make sure you check for extra admin users, change the database password and also change you admin users passwords and ftp passwords.